# Event ordering and log compaction in Kafka or Event Hubs

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, event-sourcing

Log Compaction is supported in Apache Kafka and [Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/log-compaction), but in both cases the partition key is used as "compaction key" rather than a separate event key, i.e. essentially older events will be dropped if they have the same partition key. Ordering is only guaranteed within a specific partition, so whenever events have an ordering dependency then they should be on the same partition.

How is this intended to work when there is an ordering dependency between different events that should not be compacted together?

Here's a booking example to illustrate:

```
1. SeatReserved (User: A, Seat: 1)
2. SeatCancelled (User: A, Seat: 1)
3. SeatReserved (User: A, Seat: 2)
```

Ordering matters here so they need to go on the same partition, i.e. `User` seems to make sense as partition key. However they cannot be compacted together, so the compaction/event key needs to be event name, `User` and `Seat`(?), and since in Kafka and Event Hubs the partition key and compaction/event key is the same thing then they might end up on different physical partitions and we might loose ordering.

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka clients, you can explicitly specify a partition or customize partition selection algorithm. For the latter, you can just call an existing partitioner with modified key. For example, in kafkajs you can supply this argument to producer to accomplish this.

```
{
   createPartitioner: () => {
        let f = Partitioners.DefaultPartitioner();
        return ({ topic, partitionMetadata, message }) => {
            return f({ topic, partitionMetadata, message: { key: getUser(message) } });  
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore the message key and key used for partition selection can be different.

However in `Azure Eventhub`, if you explicitly specify a partition you cannot specify a partition key and the partition selection algorithm cannot be customized to use a part of the key, so as far as I remember, there is no way to accomplish what you are describing.